# No puedo convertir un formato Json en una tabla csv

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv, pandas

He intentado convertir un json a csv, lo intenté directamente con la biblioteca `csv` y también con `pandas`, pero me dice `TypeError`.

Éste es mi código:

```
import urllib2, json
url = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations"
token = 'CPxuwmGOwFTuTrPxPPWznbfnyHHEpHiZ'
req0 = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"token":token})
req = urllib2.urlopen(req0)
jdata = req.read()

import pandas as pd
import json

def jdata(df):
   features = []
   df.apply(lambda X: features.append( 
           geojson.Feature(geometry=geojson.Point((X["long"], 
                                                X["lat"], 
                                                X["elev"])), 
               properties=dict(name=X["name"], 

   description=unicode(X["description"].decode('utf8'))))
                                )
          , axis=1)
   with open('map.geojson', 'w') as fp:
       geojson.dump(geojson.FeatureCollection(features), fp, sort_keys=True)

col = ["elevation", "mindata", "maxdata", "latitude", "name", 
"datacoverage", 
"id", "elevationUnit", "longitude"]
data = [jdata]

print (col)
print (data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que lo que quieres es guardar el campo `'results'` del JSON en un csv, existen varias formas con o sin Pandas. Te dejo una posibilidad usando simplemente Python estándar y las bibliotecas `json` y `csv`:

```
import csv
import json
import urllib2


url = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations"
token = 'CPxuwmGOwFTuTrPxPPWznbfnyHHEpHiZ'
req0 = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"token":token})
req = urllib2.urlopen(req0)
data = req.read()

jdata = json.loads(data)['results']
cols = ["elevation", "mindate", "maxdate", "latitude", "name", "datacoverage", "id", "elevationUnit", "longitude"]
with open('results.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, cols)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(jdata)
```

Con esto obtenemos el siguiente csv:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, era esto lo que realmente necesitaba!